# How to pass variables to ProcessPoolExecutor, got type error

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, typeerror, process-pool

i'm trying to modify my code to apply Parallelism with `ProcessPoolExecutor`. as i read on internet i should use `Map()` function to pass my variables to the function. but it throws typeerror, which needs iterabels. should i modify the method so it would only get one row and then  feed the variables through a for loop?

the Error:

```
    186 def _get_chunks(*iterables, chunksize):
    187     """ Iterates over zip()ed iterables in chunks. """
--> 188     it = zip(*iterables)
    189     while True:
    190         chunk = tuple(itertools.islice(it, chunksize))

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

my Code:

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    df = executor.map(drop_dupplicate_rows, df,'title',0.7,chunksize=100)

def drop_dupplicate_rows(_df,_column,_cuttoff):
  '''
  drop Duplicate rows based on difflib library 
  
  Parameters
  ----------
  df: DataFrame
    the data frame
  _column: string
    the column name to be checked for duplicates
  _cuttoff: int
    the percentage based of which rows are dropped
  Returns
  ----------
  the cleaned dataframe
  '''
  for k,row in enumerate(_df[f'{_column}']):
    repetition_list=list()    
    if not np.where(_df[f'{_column}']==''):
        repetition_list=difflib.get_close_matches(row,_df[f'{_column}'],cutoff=_cuttoff)
        if len(repetition_list)>=2:
            print(f'row:{k},link: {_df.at[k,"url"]} due to: {_column} repetition_list: ',repetition_list)
            _df.drop(index=k,inplace=True)
    _df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
  return _df
```

Comment: I understand the error but I don't understand the logic of your function. You try to apply difflib on a small subset of your dataframe. In this case, you can missed some match, no?

Comment: @Corralien no i pass whole data set and just ignore the empty ones here `if not np.where(_df[f'{_column}']==''):`, because it means the request wasn't successful so i will try again later.

Comment: Are you sure `_df` has the same size of `df`?

Comment: it will remove some rows IF they have similarities in percentage, therefor maybe not. that's actually what i wanted, because i get this data from the Server and i'm not sure if it's unique enough, sometimes the websites (LINK or URLs) that i get are the same with a little diffrenece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the implementation of your function. However, you can use `multiprocessing` with:

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def drop_dupplicate_rows(_df,_column,_cuttoff):
    # your code

# protect the entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load your dataframe here
    # df = ...

    CHUNKSIZE=100
    chunks = (df[i:i+CHUNKSIZE] for i in range(0, len(df), CHUNKSIZE))

    # create the multiprocessing pool (4 CPU)
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        partial_func = partial(drop_dupplicate_rows, _column='title', _cuttoff=0.7)
        out = pool.map(partial_func, chunks)
```

Comment: it takes longer to run this code than my actual method